# relation users to orders

Tags: views

I want to create a list of users with their orders. I know I can create it with the Views module, but when I select user as view type, there is no relation I can use to get their orders.

Some users may not have any order. I want the list to include also those users without any order.

Comment: If the reverse relation is not available, then there is no simple way. it has to be coded in the module. You can try to find a patch in the module issue queue or file a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write a custom module that implements [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7) to programmatically define a relationship. See also the example code for [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).

Comment: tnx for your attention,I know that,I ask here maybe someone has better solution